# Why do I get an error message of NoneType object is not callable when I try to call this function?

Tags: python, return, python-decorators, nonetype

```
def decorator_function(original_func):
    def wrapper_func():
        print('Run this code before the function that needs docorated')
        original_func()
        print('Run this code after the function that needs decorated has been called')
    return wrapper_func()

def function_needing_decorated():
    print('I need to be decorated')


decorator_test = decorator_function(function_needing_decorated)
```

I'm guessing it has to do with a misunderstanding of return because I'm pretty sure I shouldn't have added the parenthesis.  My question is WHY it won't work?  WHY is it a NoneType but isn't a NoneType when I don't put the parenthesis there.  The more detailed you are on this the better because I really need to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the parenthesis after the function name (`wrapper_func()`), you are actually calling the function.

Wrapper Function is being evaluated, and the value it generates is returned by `decorator_function`.

`wrapper_func()` doesn't have a return statement, so its return value is `None`, which is not callable.

`wrapper_func` on the other hand is treated as a variable--a first-class function. As a result, it is callable.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call the wrapper inside the decorator - you should return the wrapper itself.

```
return wrapper_func
```

What you are doing is returning the result of calling the wrapper; since that wrapper itself does not return anything the decorator itself is now nothing.